# How to change files at /home/ubuntu folder?

Tags: linux, windows, for-loop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, subsystem

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
I'm using the Ubuntu bash inside Windows 10 but I created a folder but can't find it on Windows filesystem.

Using bash inside windows I created a folder inside /home/ubuntu
Now I wanted to find that folder at Windows of course, set some files and change it using a notepad++ using Windows, not the bash.
Is that posible?

Comment: perhaps better suited over at superuser instead.

Comment: DOS's `dir` is equivalent to `ls` in Linux.

Comment: You don't understand the question, I'm using that Ubuntu CLI inside Windows 10 I don't know where is the folder I created on Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the WSL root changed with the official release of the Spring Creator's Update. It's now dependent on the choice of distro. With Ubuntu I found mine at:

`C:\Users\oleni\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home`

I put mine in the Quick Access menu in Explorer to get at it more easily.